# Sending UDP data hangs the receiving application

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am sending UDP packets to Hercules for testing, and whenever I send data it hangs Hecrcules.

I am not sure if it is an issue with my code.

Please have a look at my code and if it has any issues, please let me know.

```
void UDPConnect::Connect(unsigned short local_port, const char* local_addr)
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    int err;
    err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);
    if (err != 0)
    {
        //std::cout << "Failed. Error Code : " << err << std::endl;
        QMessageBox Msgbox;
        Msgbox.setText("Udp Connection Failed.");
        Msgbox.exec();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //Create a socket
    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        //  err = WSAGetLastError();
        //  std::cout << "Could not create socket : " << err << std::endl;
        QMessageBox Msgbox;
        Msgbox.setText("Could not create socket :");
        Msgbox.exec();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    struct sockaddr_in server = {};
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(local_port);
    if (local_addr)
    {
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(local_addr);
        if (server.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE)
        {
            //  std::cout << "Invalid local address specified" << std::endl;
            QMessageBox Msgbox;
            Msgbox.setText("Invalid local address specified.");
            Msgbox.exec();
            closesocket(s);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    else
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    //Bind
    if (::bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        //  err = WSAGetLastError();
        //  std::cout << "Bind failed with error code : " << err << std::endl;
        QMessageBox Msgbox;
        Msgbox.setText("Bind failed.");
        Msgbox.exec();
        closesocket(s);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int UDPConnect::SendPacket(byte *buffer, unsigned int buf_size, const  char* remote_addr, unsigned short remote_port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_other = {};
    int send_len;
    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(remote_addr);
    si_other.sin_port = htons(remote_port);

    if ((send_len = sendto(s, (char*)buffer, buf_size, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, sizeof(si_other))) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {

    }
    return send_len;
}
```

When I use the boost library to send data, I have no problem.

```
bool UDPConnect::send_udp_message(const std::string& message, const std::string& destination_ip, const unsigned short port)
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(io_service);

    // Create the remote endpoint using the destination ip address and
    // the target port number.  This is not a broadcast
    auto remote = boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(destination_ip), port);
    try {

        // Open the socket, socket's destructor will
        // automatically close it.
        socket.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());

        // And send the string... (synchronous / blocking)
        socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(message), remote);
    }
    catch (const boost::system::system_error& ex) {
        // Exception thrown!
        // Examine ex.code() and ex.what() to see what went wrong!
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: If it's hanging the receiving application, we should be looking at the code on that side.  How do you know it hangs the remote side?

Comment: The receiving application is standard software used to test for sending and receving data  on ports , its name is hercules.

Comment: How do you know the remote app is "hanging"?

Comment: When i used boost to send UDP data it works fine.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problem you're having? How do you notice the "hanging"? What really happens on the receiving side? What should happen? What output (if any) do you get? What output (if any) should you get?

Comment: Are you sure the call to `sendto` is successful?  You check its return value but don't take any action based on that value.

Comment: The application on the receiving end freezes and than i need to end task it.

Comment: @GM sure i will check that.

Comment: How are your `Connect()` and `SendPacket()` methods being called, and how is that different than how `send_udp_message()` is being called? Please provide a [mcve] showing the issue in action.

Comment: There are a few differences between your non-Boost code and the Boost code. For one thing the Boost code doesn't bind the socket, and it creates the socket for each call.

Comment: I think that might be a reason i will check this.